# Establish a socket connection Iphone with Server example from Ray Wunderlich

Tags: iphone

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

From the Python Server side

```
     from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol

     from twisted.internet import reactor


  class IphoneChat(Protocol):
def connectionMade(self):
    print "a client connected"


 factory = Factory()
 factory.protocol = IphoneChat
 reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
 print "Iphone Chat server started"
reactor.run()
```

Then on the Iphone he has

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication {

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 80, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];



[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

}

Now the question I have is from the Iphone side how does it know what's localhost is?
I could understand from the computer itself it knows what's localhost, but on a Iphone device, (NOT the simulator which is in the computer so it should know localhost).  **How does a actual Iphone knows 'localhost'??**

Comment: Are you running a python server inside the iphone??? How???

Comment: I wouldn't expect that code to work on a real device unless 'localhost' gets replaced with a hostname/ip of the server the python-script is running on.

Comment: python server is the Computer.  Iphone is the device trying to connect to it.   If he runs the app on simulator then both the server and device are the same one.

Comment: localhost is 127.0.0.1 as stated in the answer bellow. But, it is quite a pain trying to loopback with iphone simulator. If you had a real device it would work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that code isn't meant to run anywhere else than in the simulator. There it will work because 'localhost' actually **is** the computer running the python-server. On a real device 'localhost' (or 127.0.0.1) will always refer to the device itself. You have to change localhost to the ip/hostname of the python-server to get it work on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing 127.0.0.1 as ip. This is the loopback IP.

But you are using the iphone as a python server? When you pair your socket with a host, it is the remote host. You should place the server address and port in the Pairing function instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

if u run this on simulator then u have to write the localhost which means the loopback address which is **127.0.0.1** but id u install this programme on iphone device then instead of localhost you have to give the **ip address** of your system where the server is running.

Comment: Please write full words, so no 'u', etc.